# Limiting numLines in a TextArea

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-media-server

So i have a chat that i want to limit number of lines in text field. Its working but there's a glitch i can't get rid off.

```
    "> ALIGN="LEFT">SERVER Gio has connected.Gio: d Gio: d Gio: d Gio: d Gio: d Gio: d  Gio: d Gio: d Gio: d Gio: dd Gio: d Gio: dd 
Gio: d 
Gio: d 
Gio: d 
Gio: d 
Gio: d 
Gio: d
```

It's not adding more lines in text area but some html content + previous msgs are added on line 0. This is my coding.

```
var nLines:uint = ConsoleTxt.mx_internal::getTextField().numLines;
var startInt:int = 0;
var endInt:int = ConsoleTxt.mx_internal::getTextField().getLineLength(0) 
if(nLines > 7){
    ConsoleTxt.htmlText  = ConsoleTxt.mx_internal::getTextField().htmlText.substring(endInt)

    ConsoleTxt.verticalScrollPosition = ConsoleTxt.maxVerticalScrollPosition
}
```

Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are some line returns in the returned data. You can try striping them out manually before inserting the text into your textbox. Try doing a split on "\n" and joining again. Might also want to split on "\r".